# In a survey, how many people did not like either orange or apple juice (simple sets and probability question)

Tags: probability

I came across the following **sets and probability** question and I don't particularly agree with the book's answer. I am interpreting the **or** as a union $\cup$.

**The problem**

[image]

[image]

**The book's answer:** $25$

**My answer:** $25+15+10+25+20+15 = 110$

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yeah bro, I think you are correct, the book has given the answer as the number who nor like orqnge neither apple juice

Comment: I see $10+15$ at the bottom, i.e. those who dislike both (*do not like either*)

Comment: That question looks ambiguous to me. Are they looking for people who dislike at least one of the drinks, or people who dislike both?

Comment: I interpret "did not like either orange or apple juice" as 
$$
(\text{Not O}) \cap (\text{Not A})
$$
and therefore it should be 10+15=25

Comment: @Arthur given they use the word **either**, can we assume its at least one of them?

Comment: @bru1987 My point is, I think your issue it's with language, not math. You interpret it one way, the given answer the other way. At least, that's a suspicion of mine. There are 25 people who dislike both, and $110$ who dislike at least one.

Comment: I agree with @MattiP. They are asking for the cardinality of: $$(O\cup A)^{\complement}=O^{\complement}\cap A^{\complement}$$

Comment: @Arthur got it, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think the expected interpretation is **people who either like G-juice only, or none at all**, resulting in

$15 + 10 = 25$

I would have interpreted it as a union if the word **either** was ommited from the question. I am not a native speaker, however.

Answer (score 2):

- "Like either Orange Juice or Apple Juice"  could be $O \cup A$
- So "Do not like either Orange Juice or Apple Juice"  could be $(O \cup A)^c = O^c \cap A^c $ $= (O^c \cap A^c  \cap G) \cup (O^c \cap A^c  \cap G^c) $
- That is $10+15=25$